# C# WPF fix flowdocument arrangement when resize the whole window

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to make a window that has two flowdocumentreader.
This is my mainwindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="doc_compare.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:doc_compare"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Docx Compare" WindowState="Maximized">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Border Width="Auto" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <FlowDocumentReader x:Name="flowDocumentReader" ViewingMode="scroll" Width="Auto" MaxWidth="750" />
        </Border>
        <Border Width="Auto" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            <FlowDocumentReader x:Name="CompareDocument" ViewingMode="Scroll" Width="Auto" MaxWidth="1000" />
        </Border>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

But when i resize the window, first reader don't change anymore.
I want to divide the window in half, and fix each readers in half.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to divide the window in half and put a FlowDocumentReader in both halves, you need not use DockPanel. Use a Grid instead, something like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Width="Auto" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="0">
        <FlowDocumentReader x:Name="flowDocumentReader" ViewingMode="scroll" Width="Auto" MaxWidth="750" />
    </Border>
    <Border Width="Auto" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <FlowDocumentReader x:Name="CompareDocument" ViewingMode="Scroll" Width="Auto" MaxWidth="1000" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: thanks Arif, It was similar but not also. Then i can see duplicated documents in a window not divided

Comment: what do you mean by divided? I assume its the two Readers you want to have divided on the screen. If yes this solution could help you with it. The two readers should of course be fed with different documents to be able to show 2 documents side by side, if you load the same document in both then you will have duplicate files.

Comment: I didn't use the same document. But it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
     Try this,
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Grid.Row="0" Width="Auto" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                <FlowDocumentReader x:Name="flowDocumentReader" ViewingMode="scroll" Width="Auto" MaxWidth="750" />
            </Border>
            <Border Grid.Row="1" Width="Auto" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                <FlowDocumentReader x:Name="CompareDocument" ViewingMode="Scroll" Width="Auto" MaxWidth="1000" />
            </Border>
        </Grid>
```